# In R, if/then statement to incorporate fields from one dataframe to another?

Tags: r, dataframe

I built a predictive model off of a data frame (DF1). I now want to apply that model to a different data frame (DF2) that contains some of the variables from DF1, but not all.

What I need to do is create an if/then statement, function, etc. that will delete variables that exist in DF2 but not in DF1 and create a column of 0's for variables that exist in DF1 but not in DF2.

Here is what the initial datasets look like:

```
# DF_1
cust_id<- c(1234,1235,1236,1237,1238) 
var_1<- c(4,5,7,8,7) 
var_2<- c(7,9,7,8,9) 
var_3<- c(5,7,8,5,4) 
df_1<- data.frame(cust_id,var_1,var_2,var_3) 

# DF_2
cust_id<- c(2123,2124,2125,2126,2127) 
var_1<- c(45,45,48,38,48) 
var_4<- c(65,62,61,57,48) 
var_5<- c(15,18,14,25,23) 
df_2<- data.frame(cust_id,var_1,var_4,var_5) 

df_1
df_2
```

Manually coding it, this is what the final dataset should look like:

```
# DF_2b
cust_id<- c(2123,2124,2125,2126,2127) 
var_1<- c(45,45,48,38,48) 
var_2<- 0 
var_3<- 0
df_2b<- data.frame(cust_id,var_1,var_2,var_3) 

df_2b
```

So what I need is code that would delete **var_4** and **var_5** from **df_2** and insert columns of zeros titled **var_2** and **var_3** into **df_2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
df <- df_2[, intersect(names(df_2), names(df_1))]
df[, setdiff(names(df_1), names(df_2))] <- 0
df
```

output

```
    cust_id var_1 var_2 var_3
 1    2123    45     0     0
 2    2124    45     0     0
 3    2125    48     0     0
 4    2126    38     0     0
 5    2127    48     0     0
```

Comment: Brilliant.. Thank you!